# Spring TransactionTemplate called from a @Transaction method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I've a particular flow calls in my Spring app.

I've a repository, and I call the method sell() as first call.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceRepositoryImpl implements ServiceRepository {

@Inject
private SellRepository sellRepository;

@Override
public long sell(long id)
   ....
   .... 
   .... 
   Sell sell = new Sell();
   ...
   sellRepository.save(sell);
}
```

and my SellService:

```
@Service
public class SellRepositoryImpl implements SellRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
SellHelperRepository sellHelperRepository;

@Inject
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Override   
public <S extends Sell> S save(S sell) throws Exception {       

    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<S>() {
        @Override
        public S doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            try {
                ...
                entityManager.persist(sell);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error("", e);
                status.setRollbackOnly();
            }
            return vendita;
        }
    });     

    sellHelperRepository.createTickets(sell.getId());


    return vendita;
}
```

this is my sellHelperRepository:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SellHelperRepositoryImpl implements SellHelperRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Async  
public void createTickets(long sellID) {
     Sell sell = entityManager.find(Sell.class, sellID);
     try{
         ...
         Ticket t = new Ticket();
         ticketService.save(t);
     }catch(Throwable e){
        sell.setStatus("CANCELED");
     }
 }
```

and in the end my ticketService:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TicketRepositoryImpl implements TicketRepository {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Biglietto save(Ticket ticket) throws Exception {
      entityManager.persist(ticket);
}
```

The problem is that in this chain of calls when I'm on SellRepositoryImpl, the object sell is not persisted asap I'm out of the transactiontemplate but it should be! So when I enter in SellHelperRepositoryImpl and I try to search the sell it doesn't find it!

This particular structure is needed because these methods are used also from others repository.
I created many junit tests case to check if all works fine; for the rest of tests all works fine, a part for this particular chain of calls.

I think I'm missing something....

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

the problem with your code is that you are using the `@Async` on the `createTickets` method , which forces Spring to execute it in the different thread with the "fresh" transaction, so you need to flush/commit first transaction which was opened in the `SellRepositoryImpl` class.
So you can go in three ways

- Remove the `@Async` from the `createTickets` method
- Change the Transaction Isolation Level from `DEFAULT` to `READ_UNCOMMITTED` in `SellHelperRepositoryImpl`

  ```
  @Service
  @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
  public class SellHelperRepositoryImpl implements SellHelperRepository          {

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      @Override
      @Async  
      public void createTickets(long sellID) {
          Sell sell = entityManager.find(Sell.class, sellID);
          try{
              ...
              Ticket t = new Ticket();
              ticketService.save(t);
           }catch(Throwable e){
              sell.setStatus("CANCELED");
           }
       }
  ```
- Flush the manually managed transaction in `save(S sell)`, see following code snippet.

  ```
  @Override   
  public <S extends Sell> S save(S sell) throws Exception {       

      transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<S>() {
          @Override
          public S doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
              try {
                  ...
                  entityManager.persist(sell);
                  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
                  status.flush();
              } catch (Throwable e) {
                  log.error("", e);
                  status.setRollbackOnly();
              }
              return vendita;
          }
      });     

      sellHelperRepository.createTickets(sell.getId());
      return vendita;
  }
  ```

Comment: I tried the 3th solution but it doesn't work. The transaction is not commited at the end of the stuff transactionTemplate.execute().

Comment: Sorry I don't have an running IDE on this pc, so please try to commit the transacton manually by entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); I have adjusted the code.

Comment: I can't use entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); because otherwise I've Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead. For now the working solution is to set PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW in the transactionTemplate.